# Why has this function a branch point

Tags: complex-analysis

In the paper freely available at the link http://www.lassp.cornell.edu/sethna/pubPDF/ZeroRadiusOfConvergencePRL.pdf,
the authors Claim that the function (I omit constants inconsequential for the present discussion, the full Expression is denoted as equation (8) in the paper)

$$Z(P) = \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}l\mathrm{d}v \,\,exp\{-l-v^2-Plv\}$$

is holomorphic in the complex P plane except for a branch cut $P\in (-\infty,0)$.

I do not see how to say the function is holomorphic except the said branch cut.

I have tried to simplify the integral but get to a point further which progress is not possible to me

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}v \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}l \,\,exp\{-l-v^2-Plv\} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}v \,\, exp\{v^2\} -\frac{1}{1+Pv}  $$

How can I confirm the function is holomorphic? Many thanks

Comment: Hint: Consider the even more simplified function
$f(P)=\int_0^\infty e^{-Pv}dv.$ This integral  does not converge for real $P\le 0$.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe I do not understand yet well what a branch cut is: the fact that a function is not defined for certain values seemed to me not to imply there is a branch cut. For example, $$f(z) = 1/z^2$$ is not defined in the origin, which is however not a branch point. Have to understand this better.

Comment: I don't know in this example how to figure it out but it has something to do with the moving singularities.

For example, $1/(P-l)$ has poles in $P=l$ and interating with respect to $dl$ in some path creates a branch cut for the integral along this path.